# Google apps script PDF fit to page

Tags: google-apps-script

I'm using a script to create a PDF-file of a sheet and save it. Everything works great except I can't figure out how to make it "fit whole page". The code below is for "fit to width" (fitw=true) which is described numerous places – but I can't find how to fit to page instead.

```js
function savePdf(spreadsheetId, sheetName, pdfName, pdfFolderId) {
  
  var sheetId = spreadsheetId.getSheetByName(sheetName).getSheetId();
  var url_base = spreadsheetId.getUrl().replace(/edit$/,'');
  
  var url_ext = 'export?exportFormat=pdf&format=pdf'
  + '&gid=' + sheetId
  // following parameters are optional...
  + '&range=D4:AX74'
  + '&size=A4'      // paper size: legal / letter / A4
  + '&portrait=false'    // orientation, false for landscape
  + '&fitw=true'        // fit to width, false for actual size
  + '&top_margin=0.50'
  + '&bottom_margin=0.50'
  + '&left_margin=0.50'
  + '&right_margin=0.50'
  + '&sheetnames=false' // 
  + '&printtitle=false'
  + '&pagenumbers=false'  //hide optional headers and footers
  + '&gridlines=false'  // hide gridlines
  + '&fzr=true';       // false = do not repeat row headers (frozen rows) on each page
  var url_options = {headers: {'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + ScriptApp.getOAuthToken(),}};
  var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url_base + url_ext, url_options);
  var blob = response.getBlob().getAs('application/pdf').setName(pdfName + '.pdf');
  var folder = DriveApp.getFolderById(pdfFolderId);
  folder.createFile(blob);
}
```

Comment: Could you share a copy of your spreadsheet? Otherwise I cannot see how the result looks like in your case.

Comment: Sure, I've just created a document: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1nCK_681Vf4DMBrwp-cuOWhhWRJfwh669ICVsN4_VTfM/edit?usp=sharing

Answer (score 6):

I've found a solution!
It's to add
  + '&scale=' + scale
  // 1 = Normal 100% -- 2 = Fit to width -- 3 = Fit to height -- 4 = Fit to Page

Comment: Thanks! The scale option works beautifully, although it is not documented.

Comment: I tried the scale option but it did not fit the pdf to the size of the page.

Comment: Even worse: I just spent a lot of time trying to figure out why images imported into a cell weren't appearing in the PDFs I'm making even though they display in the Sheet. I tracked it down to this bit of advice; shame on me for not noticing the problem when it first happened. Once I removed the '&scale=4' from the URL, the images reappeared in the PDFs.

Comment: For me also it didn't work.

Answer (score 1):

This should do it:

&horizontal_alignment=CENTER

Answer (score 0):

The `fitw` parameter should work as expected, but I found a reported [issue](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/36765338) and I can also experience this problem. Using or not using it does not make any difference.

You can click on the star next to the issue number to receive updates and to give more priority to the bug.

Comment: fitw works fine for me – but that's fit to WIDTH – I'm looking for fit to PAGE.

Answer (score 0):

I have tried all the things, I was using `fitw=false` with `scale=4` and   `fith=true&source=labnol` but it didn't work for me. I am printing some range in which some rows are having `fit to data` height and some rows have `fixed forced` height.

Finally the following works for me.

I used `fitw=true` with `scale=3` and `fith=true&source=labnol` . The whole link I used is as follow:

```
var url = "https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/" + spreadsheetID + "/export" +
          "?format=pdf&" + "gid=" + sheetId + "&range=" +
          rng +"&"+ // rng="A1:Z50"
          "size=2&" +
          "fzr=true&" +
          "portrait=true&" +
          "fitw=true&" +
          "pageorder=1&"+
          "gridlines=false&" +
          "printtitle=false&" +
          "sheetnames=false&" +
          "pagenum=false&" +
          "horizontal_alignment=CENTER&" +
          "vertical_alignment=TOP&" +
          "top_margin=0.6&left_margin=0.3&right_margin=0.25&bottom_margin=0.258&" +
          "scale=3&" +
          "fith=true&source=labnol&"+
          "attachment=true";
```

I hope it will be helpful to you.